# How do I only get values from Django queryset?

Tags: python, django

So I have a filtered QuerySet with a specific field, that looks like this: 
`[{'category':'book'}, {'category':'food'}, {'category':'movie'}, {'category':'book'}, {'category':'style'}, ...]`.

I now want to make a list that only contains the values(book, food, movie, style), with no duplicates. How do I make it possible? Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you please include the `QuerySet`, or at least part of it?

Comment: A queryset is not an array, please provide THE `Queryset` as Willem Van Onsem said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `.distinct()` on it to retrieve the value only once. Furthermore instead of using `.values('category')`, you can use `.values_list('category', flat=True)` to obtain a collection that only contains the categories.

So the queryset should look like:

```
SomeModel.objects.values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
```

That being said, based on how you retrieve data, it looks like you have *data duplication*. You for example store the name of a category, instead of making a `Category` model and link to that category.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. The reason why I didn't make a separate model for referencing, is because each user can make his/her own categories. That's why I had to leave it as a field. Thanks again :)